# Accessing #1 in the end part of a new environment declaration

Tags: graphics, captions, margins, memoir

I'm working to a document in memoir and I'm struggling trying to define a new environment which would allow me to place a figure in the main text and its caption in the outer margin. This is an extract of my preamble without the definition of such environment.

```
\documentclass[10pt]{memoir}                        %document class
\setstocksize{240mm}{150mm}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}                            %font output
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}                         %font input
\usepackage[english]{babel} 

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{marginfix}
\usepackage{graphicx}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% PAGE LAYOUT
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\usepackage{geometry}

\let\footruleskip\undefined                         %headings
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\nouppercaseheads

\settrimmedsize{240mm}{150mm}{*}
\setlength{\trimtop}{0pt}
\setlength{\trimedge}{\stockwidth}
\addtolength{\trimedge}{-\paperwidth}
\settypeblocksize{193mm}{84mm}{*}
\setulmargins{27mm}{*}{*}
\setlrmargins{18mm}{*}{*}
\setmarginnotes{3mm}{3.5cm}{\onelineskip}
\setheadfoot{\onelineskip}{\onelineskip}
\setlength{\headsep}{1.2cm}
%\setheaderspaces{*}{2\onelineskip}{*}
\checkandfixthelayout

\addtolength{\footskip}{0.55cm}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% CAPTION LAYOUT
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\usepackage{caption}                                %customized captions
\captionsetup{font=footnotesize, labelfont={bf}}
\usepackage{captdef}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% FULLWIDTH
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\usepackage[outermargin=-3.5cm]{fullwidth}

\newenvironment{fullwidthblocked}{%
\blockmargin%
\begin{fullwidth}%
}{%
\end{fullwidth}%
\unblockmargin%
}
```

I thought I could use `fullwidthblocked` to define the new environment, so I tried this solution

```
\newenvironment{figureDX}[1]{%
\begin{fullwidthblocked}%
\begin{minipage}{84mm}%
\centering%
#1%
\end{minipage}%
\hspace{1.5mm}%
\begin{minipage}{3.5cm}%
}{%
\end{minipage}%
\end{fullwidthblocked}%
}
```

which can be used in the main text writing

```
\begin{figureDX}{\includegraphics[scale=•]{•}}
\figcaption{•}\label{•}
\end{figureDX}
```

This actually works, but it is good only for odd pages, since it puts the caption to the right of the image. I then tried to adapt this few lines to introduce their even pages counterpart:

```
\newenvironment{figureSX}[1]{%
\begin{fullwidthblocked}%
\begin{minipage}{3.5cm}%
}{%
\end{minipage}%
\hspace{1.5mm}%
\begin{minipage}{84mm}%
#1%
\end{minipage}%
\end{fullwidthblocked}%
}
```

but this returns the error `! Illegal parameter number in definition of \endfigureSX.` which I don't know how to solve.

I'm aware the solution I'm proposing is not elegant nor compact, but at least I'd like it to work.. Any ideas how could I fix this?

Comment: `\newenvironment` does not allow you to access `#1`  in the end part of the env. You can try using `xparse` its enviroment creating tools can

Comment: I have just defined the new environment using `xparse` as you suggested, and it works without problems with the rest of my preamble. Thank you so much!

Comment: BTW: for future visitors, it might be an idea to make the title of the question reflect the actual problem. Which is not making a margin figure, but rather accessing `#1` in the end part of a new environment declaration

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In normal LaTeX2e the `\newenvironment` construction does not allow access to `#1` in the end part of the environment.

LaTeX3, in this case, `xparse` to the rescue. It provides

```
\NewDocumentEnvironment{envname}{ arg specification }{ start }{ end }
```

with the addition that `#1` is accessible from the end part. Note that `arg specification` is very different from the number based one used by `\newenvironment`.